# Why is solo dancing not as popular as contra and partner dancing?

Tags: social-psychology

I have been to dance lessons. They only taught partner dancing and cobtra dancing. No solo dancing was taught at all. In Sweden where I'm from solo dancing is kind of unpopular. In music on the other hand you have both solo and ensemble being popular.
What are some psychological theories that speak about this in some way or another? And what theories are generally accepted as scientific.

Comment: FWIW: https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/blog/millennial-media/201310/is-pole-dancing-actually-empowering-women but more recently https://www.dailydot.com/irl/strippers-pole-dancers-sex-work-debate/

Answer (score 1):

Should be something associated with [Courtship Display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtship_display). Not entirely sure if this explains entire thing fully. There might be some other factors.

Comment: But don't people like playing alobe?

Comment: I think that sexual elements displayed in wide majority of dances give extra pleasurable element to it.